# How to: Apply Noise to Histograms to generate new Histograms

Tags: math, statistics, histogram, distribution, probability

Im working on a problem where i need to work with some bimodal histograms. Like on the example below. Im using those histograms to train a Neural Network to identify bimodal standarts on histograms. I represent those histograms as a numeric vector, like on the example below:

```
8029, 41, 82, 177, 135, 255, 315, 591, 949, 456, 499, 688, 446, 733, 712, 1595, 2633, 3945, 6134, 9755, 9236, 11911, 11888, 9450, 13119, 8819, 5991, 4399, 6745, 2017, 3747, 1777, 2946, 1623, 2151, 454, 3015, 3176, 2211, 1080, 391, 580, 750
```

Well, i have like 300 bimodal histograms(an example of bimodal histogram is on the image below),

[image: Bimodal Histogram Sample]

but to train the Network, it would be nice to have like 2000 histograms. I know i can generate new histograms by just apply some 'noise' on the histograms i have. A'noised' histogram would be still bimodal and very like the original histogram it were generated from, but it would represent a 'new data', so the Neural Network can have more examples to learn.

Someone have an idea of how can i add 'noise' to my histograms?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you add uniform noise in range ±k. There are Hi pixels in the i-th bin. Each will be transformed in some i+j, where -k≤j≤k, with probability 1/(2k+1).

Hence on average a single bin gets evenly spread over 2k+1 neighboring bins. This effect is just that of a convolution of the histogram with a square signal.

Similar reasoning shows that for other noise distributions, you just convolve the histogram with the PDF of the distribution.

---

This process corresponds to the expected effect of noise addition, as the bins are perturbed in a balanced way. If you want a more random simulation, you can replace the PDF at every bin by the histogram of a random drawing following that distribution with as many samples as there are pixels in the bin (or a smaller number, correcting the frequencies accordingly).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I got what you mean, but i cant visualize it. Could you make an example with any numeric array? It can be the example above.

Comment: Take a running average of your data.